# por que usuario e criado mas senha não funciona?

Tags: python, linux

Boa Tarde pessoal estou montando um script para criar usuário e senha no linux (ubuntu 16.04LTS).
O problema e que após rodar o meu script o usuário e criado mas não consigo logar com a senha que foi passada pelo script. Alguem sabe o motivo?? Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
import subprocess
import sys

#criar usuario e senha 
nome  = input('Digite o nome do usuario: ')
senha = input('Digite a senha do usuario: ')
dominio = input('Digite o Dominio: ')

# user
user_sufix = nome
user_name = 'teste_' + user_sufix

# password
user_pass = senha

# domain
domain = dominio


#Cria o usuario na maquina
useradd_result = subprocess.run(["sudo", "useradd","-m","-p",user_pass, "-s", "/bin/bash",])
#passwd_result = subprocess.run(['sudo','passwd',user_name,user_pass])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando você usa o comando `useradd` passando a senha, **ela já deve estar criptografada**.

Então faça isso usando o comando `openssl passwd` antes. Capture a saída desse comando com o atributo `stdout`, passando o argumento `subprocess.PIPE` para o parâmetro `stdout` do método `run()`.

O resultado é uma sequência de bytes, que você deve decodificar e remover o caractere *newline* do final.

Ficaria assim, antes da execução do `useradd`:

```
user_pass = subprocess.run(['openssl', 'passwd', senha], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

Depois disso você pode usar `user_pass` como argumento para o `useradd`.

Comment: Valeu Guilherme. consegui aqui.